# Dead battery in brand new acer travel mate, have the warranty, how to repair?

Tags: laptop, battery, warranty, acer-travelmate

Couple of days back I bought a brand new acer travel mate 253-M from amazon.de, but the battery is not being charged at all, seems the battery is dead. I'm not located in Germany, but I have the warranty card.

This might not be a computer related question, but I'm a little lost: if I want use the warranty card, do I have to send it back to Germany? Or can I walk into a local computer repair shop, tell them about the battery and show them the warranty, and they'll repair it?

Thanks!

Comment: you should contact amazon.de. Here in canada the battery waranty is 30 days. Don't know in Germany but, don't lose  time :)

Comment: Thanks, but do I have to send it back to Germany for the repair?!

Comment: @Mathmath, phone up a local shop and ask them! Contact amazon.de and ask them. This question is about warranty, it's not about computers in any way

Comment: If you walk into a random computer repair shop they will expect you to pay them.  The warranty is only good if you send it to Acer, allow them to repair it on their terms, and have them ship it back to you.

Comment: You should ask Amazon support. Only they can give you a definitive answer.

Comment: Contact Acer and find a (more) local authorized repair shop.

Answer (score 2):

You should contact whoever issued the warranty card (Acer or Amazon.de) and ask them. Each warranty will have different terms, conditions, time limits and so forth. We really would not know here.

As an aside, I would advise you use the warranty, unless:

1. You absolutely need it repaired sooner than they can repair it under warranty, or
2. Their warranty service is notoriously terrible, to the point at which it is actually going to make things worse.

Either way, you will end up paying for it, but still come out ahead. If neither of those apply to you, consider using the card. That's what it's there for!